# Write Data in new rows in Excel file MATLAB from While loop

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, while-loop

I have a code which looks like something like this-

```
disp([' It.: ' sprintf('%4i',loop) ' Obj.: ' sprintf('%10.4f',c) ...
                   ' Vol.: ' sprintf('%6.3f',sum(sum(x))/ (nelx*nely)) ...
                   ' ch.: ' sprintf('%6.3f',change )])
```

This code displays the different variables running from While loop. 
where

```
loop= iteration number of the while loop
c= factor that I want to write to my result file
```

I used a code like this-

```
    A=[loop;c];
    fileID = fopen('exp.csv','w');
    formatSpec ='%4i,%10.4f\n';
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,A);
    fclose(fileID);
```

My problem is, I can not write the data (values of Loop and C) to a single excel/CSV file. I tried searching the internet but all solutions are for `for` loop where the iteration number is known. In my code, I am running `while` loop where I don't know the iteration number. 
I tried different ways but it only overwrites my previous data and gets me a single line of result with the final iteration.

> I want to create a **CSV/Excel** file in **MATLAB** with two columns, in the First column, there will be the value of `loop` (while loop iteration number of my code) and in second column there will be the value of `C`.

I am quite new in MATLAB so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: You tried different ways like...what? Writing lines to a CSV inside your loop should be a trivial use of [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).

Comment: @excaza thanks for your reply. 
I used the following code - 
filename = 'compliance.csv';         
    csvwrite(filename,c)

Comment: I also edited my code like this, still a single line answer
'A=[loop;c];
    fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
    formatSpec ='%4i,%10.4f\n';
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,A);
    fclose(fileID);'

Comment: Please read the documentation for things before you use them. [The documentation for `fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#inputarg_permission) clearly states that the `'w'` permission discards any existing file contents, so you don't want to do this inside of the loop. Open your file outside the loop, enter the loop, then close the file when the loop is done.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y4YSA9HglKhCmdqQqwTiySquv1Ni9ezR/view?usp=sharing]
here is my full code, even after putting my `fopen` command out of my while loop I see this error message - 
**Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to
generate a valid file identifier.**

Comment: @excaza my problem is solved, :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For writing data in while loop I used the following code

`fileID = fopen('exp.csv','w');
while (condition)
    **some other commands to calculate the values**
    disp([' It.: ' sprintf('%4i',loop) ' Obj.: ' sprintf('%10.4f',c) ...
                   ' Vol.: ' sprintf('%6.3f',sum(sum(x))/ (nelx*nely)) ...
                   ' ch.: ' sprintf('%6.3f',change )])
    A=[loop;c];
    fileID = fopen('exp.csv','a');
    formatSpec ='%4i,%10.4f\n';
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,A);
    fclose(fileID);
end`